# What 'something' ? 'something' : 'something' operator means?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I found some code from https://github.com/andrewgodwin

```
    var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
```

What does `'something' ? 'something' : 'something'` means?

Comment: `?:` is the ternary operator. It is a short and often gorgeous method of writing a simple `if` statement in many languages.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called conditional (ternary) operator. This operator is frequently used as a shortcut for the if statement. If the condition before the "?" is true then the value just after the "?" is assigned to the variable, else the value after ":" is assigned to the variable.

Details at: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

It is conditional operator in javascript ref. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

Answer (score 2):

```
var ws_scheme = window.location.protocol == "https:" ? "wss" : "ws";
```

that means:

```
var ws_scheme;
if (window.location.protocol == "https:") {
    ws_scheme = "wss";
} else {
    ws_scheme = "ws";
}
```